# How to evenly change track height for slider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, material-design

My code:

```
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: SliderTheme(
              data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xff8d8e98),
                activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                thumbColor: Color(0xffeb1555),
                overlayColor: Color(0x29eb1555),
                thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15),
                overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30),
                trackHeight: 2,                                             
              ),
              child: Slider(
                value: 183,
                min: 10,
                max: 270,
                onChanged: (double value) {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I got this:

[image: bad]

I expected this:

[image: OK]

How can I get it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a liitle bit late, but, as I just solved that to myself, I thought it could be useful to others:

You should include, in the SliderTheme data the following:

```
trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
```

And that is it, you will get both active and inactive track with the same height!

Answer (score 15):

If you must use the `RoundedRectSliderTrackShape()` specifically as you need the rounded edge, then simply create a `CustomTrackShape()` and override the value of `additionalActiveTrackHeight` to 0.

```
class CustomTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
 
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset,
      {required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required Offset thumbCenter,
      bool isDiscrete = false,
      bool isEnabled = false,
      double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 2}) {

    super.paint(context, offset,
        parentBox: parentBox,
        sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
        enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
        textDirection: textDirection,
        thumbCenter: thumbCenter,
        isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
        isEnabled: isEnabled,
        additionalActiveTrackHeight: 0);
  }

}
```

Comment: when I use this code I am getting errors.



`Error: The argument type 'TextDirection/*1*/' can't be assigned
to the parameter type 'TextDirection/*2*/'.
 - 'TextDirection/*1*/' is from 'package:intl/src/intl/text_direction.dart'
 ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.17.0/lib/src/intl/text_direction.dart').
 - 'TextDirection/*2*/' is from 'dart:ui'.
        textDirection: textDirection,`

Comment: working fine now. previously I have written in the same file. when I change the code to a new file this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Just update trackHeight to 1. This would make it better.

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: SliderTheme(
              data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xff8d8e98),
                activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                thumbColor: Color(0xffeb1555),
                overlayColor: Color(0x29eb1555),
                thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15),
                overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30),
                trackHeight: 1,                                             
              ),
              child: Slider(
                value: 183,
                min: 10,
                max: 270,
                onChanged: (double value) {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This does not match the height of both tracks. Can u please explain?