# How do you make the flutter Slider track the same height on each side of the thumb?

Tags: flutter, slider

I've written a flutter `Slider` and incorporated a `SliderTheme` in order to be able to configure the activeTrackColor etc.

But I cannot find a setting to prevent the height of the track changing when the thumb passes over it. The track on the 'active' side (i.e. between the `min` position and the thumb) is always slightly bigger than the 'inactive side.

Is there a setting either in `SliderTheme` or elsewhere that will keep the track height constant? (I have tried setting `trackHeight` but this doesn't prevent the height changing.

Comment: I think someone already answered it.
Check out the link
[How to make flutter slider height uniformly equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527693/how-to-evenly-change-track-height-for-slider-in-flutter)